# Programmatic type annotations in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, metaprogramming, type-systems, hindley-milner

When metaprogramming, it may be useful (or necessary) to pass along to Haskell's type system information about types that's known to your program but not inferable in Hindley-Milner. Is there a library (or language extension, etc) that provides facilities for doing this—that is, programmatic type annotations—in Haskell?

Consider a situation where you're working with a heterogenous list (implemented using the `Data.Dynamic` library or existential quantification, say) and you want to filter the list down to a bog-standard, homogeneously typed Haskell list. You can write a function like

```
import Data.Dynamic
import Data.Typeable

dynListToList :: (Typeable a) => [Dynamic] -> [a]
dynListToList = (map fromJust) . (filter isJust) . (map fromDynamic)
```

and call it with a manual type annotation. For example,

```
foo :: [Int]
foo = dynListToList [ toDyn (1 :: Int)
                    , toDyn (2 :: Int)
                    , toDyn ("foo" :: String) ]
```

Here `foo` is the list `[1, 2] :: [Int]`; that works fine and you're back on solid ground where Haskell's type system can do its thing.

Now imagine you want to do much the same thing but (a) at the time you write the code you don't know what the type of the list produced by a call to `dynListToList` needs to be, yet (b) your program does contain the information necessary to figure this out, only (c) it's not in a form accessible to the type system.

For example, say you've randomly selected an item from your heterogenous list and you want to filter the list down by *that* type. Using the type-checking facilities supplied by `Data.Typeable`, your program has all the information it needs to do this, but as far as I can tell—this is the essence of the question—there's no way to pass it along to the type system. Here's some pseudo-Haskell that shows what I mean:

```
import Data.Dynamic
import Data.Typeable

randList :: (Typeable a) => [Dynamic] -> IO [a]
randList dl = do
    tr <- randItem $ map dynTypeRep dl
    return (dynListToList dl :: [<tr>])  -- This thing should have the type
                                         -- represented by `tr`
```

(Assume `randItem` selects a random item from a list.)

Without a type annotation on the argument of `return`, the compiler will tell you that it has an "ambiguous type" and ask you to provide one. But you can't provide a manual type annotation because the type is not known at write-time (and can vary); the type *is* known at run-time, however—albeit in a form the type system can't use (here, the type needed is represented by the value `tr`, a `TypeRep`—see `Data.Typeable` for details).

The pseudo-code `:: [<tr>]` is the magic I want to happen. Is there any way to provide the type system with type information programatically; that is, with type information contained in a value in your program?

Basically I'm looking for a function with (pseudo-) type `??? -> TypeRep -> a` that takes a value of a type unknown to Haskell's type system and a `TypeRep` and says, "Trust me, compiler, I know what I'm doing. This thing has the value represented by this `TypeRep`." (Note that this is *not* what `unsafeCoerce` does.)

Or is there something completely different that gets me the same place? For example, I can imagine a language extension that permits assignment to type variables, like a souped-up version of the extension enabling scoped type variables.

(If this is impossible or highly impractical,—e.g., it requires packing a complete GHCi-like interpreter into the executable—please try to explain why.)

Comment: With `import Data.Maybe`, `dynListToList = mapMaybe fromDynamic`.

Comment: @AntalS-Z—Good simplification.

Comment: As you said, in your example the type information is only available at runtime, so there's no way you could have it during type-check phase (which happens at compile time). There is no way to ever implement your pseudo-code example because it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I'm having a hard time keeping track of how many architectural red flags there are in this question. If you need to do this, you will probably benefit a lot from flagging down an experienced Haskeller in the hallway and chatting with them for an hour or two about how to start over.

Comment: @DanielWagner: I wish there were an experienced Haskeller down the hallway! Regardless, this is meant as an exploration of the limits of Haskell's type system. But there are indeed problems that require either doing something very much like this or (worse, from an architectural standpoint) a complete end-run around the type system.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you can't do this.  The long and short of it is that you're trying to write a dependently-typed function, and Haskell isn't a dependently typed language; you can't lift your `TypeRep` value to a true type, and so there's no way to write down the type of your desired function.  To explain this in a little more detail, I'm first going to show why the way you've phrased the type of `randList` doesn't really make sense.  Then, I'm going to explain why you can't do what you want.  Finally, I'll briefly mention a couple thoughts on what to actually do.

### Existentials

Your type signature for `randList` can't mean what you want it to mean.  Remembering that all type variables in Haskell are universally quantified, it reads

```
randList :: forall a. Typeable a => [Dynamic] -> IO [a]
```

Thus, I'm entitled to call it as, say, `randList dyns :: IO [Int]` anywhere I want; I must be able to provide a return value for *all* `a`, not simply for *some* `a`.  Thinking of this as a game, it's one where the *caller* can pick `a`, not the function itself.  What you *want* to say (this isn't valid Haskell syntax, although you can translate it into valid Haskell by using an existential data type<sup>1</sup>) is something more like

```
randList :: [Dynamic] -> (exists a. Typeable a => IO [a])
```

This promises that the elements of the list are of *some* type `a`, which is an instance of `Typeable`, but not necessarily *any* such type.  But even with this, you'll have two problems.  First, even if you could construct such a list, what could you do with it?  And second, it turns out that you can't even construct it in the first place.

Since all that you know about the elements of the existential list is that they're instances of `Typeable`, what can you do with them?  [Looking at the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Typeable.html), we see that there are only two functions<sup>2</sup> which take instances of `Typeable`:

- [`typeOf :: Typeable a => a -> TypeRep`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Typeable.html#v:typeOf), from the type class itself (indeed, the only method therein); and
- [`cast :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Typeable.html#v:cast) (which is implemented with `unsafeCoerce`, and couldn't be written otherwise).

Thus, all that you know about the type of the elements in the list is that you can call `typeOf` and `cast` on them.  Since we'll never be able to usefully do anything else with them, our existential might just as well be (again, not valid Haskell)

```
randList :: [Dynamic] -> IO [(TypeRep, forall b. Typeable b => Maybe b)]
```

This is what we get if we apply `typeOf` and `cast` to every element of our list, store the results, and throw away the now-useless existentially typed original value.  Clearly, the `TypeRep` part of this list isn't useful.  And the second half of the list isn't either.  Since we're back to a universally-quantified type, the caller of `randList` is once again entitled to request that they get a `Maybe Int`, a `Maybe Bool`, or a `Maybe b` for any (typeable) `b` of their choosing.  (In fact, they have slightly more power than before, since they can instantiate different elements of the list to different types.)  But they can't figure out what type they're converting *from* unless they already know it—you've still lost the type information you were trying to keep.

And even setting aside the fact that they're not useful, you simply can't construct the desired existential type here.  The error arises when you try to return the existentially-typed list (`return $ dynListToList dl`).  At what specific type are you calling `dynListToList`?  Recall that `dynListToList :: forall a. Typeable a => [Dynamic] -> [a]`; thus, `randList` is responsible for picking *which* `a` `dynListToList` is going to use.  But it doesn't know which `a` to pick; again, that's the source of the question!  So the type that you're trying to return is underspecified, and thus ambiguous.<sup>3</sup>

### Dependent types

OK, so what would *make* this existential useful (and possible)?  Well, we actually have slightly more information: not only do we know there's *some* `a`, we have its `TypeRep`.  So maybe we can package that up:

```
randList :: [Dynamic] -> (exists a. Typeable a => IO (TypeRep,[a]))
```

This isn't quite good enough, though; the `TypeRep` and the `[a]` aren't linked at all.  And that's exactly what you're trying to express: some way to link the `TypeRep` and the `a`.

Basically, your goal is to write something like

```
toType :: TypeRep -> *
```

Here, `*` is the kind of all types; if you haven't seen kinds before, they are to types what types are to values.  `*` classifies types, `* -> *` classifies one-argument type constructors, etc.  (For instance, `Int :: *`, `Maybe :: * -> *`, `Either :: * -> * -> *`, and `Maybe Int :: *`.)

With this, you could write (once again, this code isn't valid Haskell; in fact, it really bears only a passing resemblance to Haskell, as there's no way you could write it or anything like it within Haskell's type system):

```
randList :: [Dynamic] -> (exists (tr :: TypeRep).
                           Typeable (toType tr) => IO (tr, [toType tr]))
randList dl = do
  tr <- randItem $ map dynTypeRep dl
  return (tr, dynListToList dl :: [toType tr])
    -- In fact, in an ideal world, the `:: [toType tr]` signature would be
    -- inferable.
```

Now, you're promising the right thing: not that there exists some type which classifies the elements of the list, but that there exists some `TypeRep` such that its corresponding type classifies the elements of the list.  If only you could do this, you would be set.  But writing `toType :: TypeRep -> *` is completely impossible in Haskell: doing this requires a dependently-typed language, since `toType tr` is a type which depends on a value.

What does this mean?  In Haskell, it's perfectly acceptable for values to depend on other values; this is what a function is.  The value `head "abc"`, for instance, depends on the value `"abc"`.  Similarly, we have type constructors, so it's acceptable for types to depend on other types; consider `Maybe Int`, and how it depends on `Int`.  We can even have values which depend on types!  Consider `id :: a -> a`.  This is really a family of functions: `id_Int :: Int -> Int`, `id_Bool :: Bool -> Bool`, etc.  Which one we have depends on the type of `a`.  (So really, `id = \(a :: *) (x :: a) -> x`; although we can't write this in Haskell, there are languages where we can.)

Crucially, however, we can never have a type that depends on a value.  We might *want* such a thing: imagine `Vec 7 Int`, the type of length-7 lists of integers.  Here, `Vec :: Nat -> * -> *`: a type whose first argument must be a value of type `Nat`.  But we can't write this sort of thing in Haskell.<sup>4</sup>  Languages which support this are called *dependently-typed* (and will let us write `id` as we did above); examples include [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/) and [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php).  (Such languages often double as proof assistants, and are generally used for research work as opposed to writing actual code.  Dependent types are hard, and making them useful for everyday programming is an active area of research.)

Thus, in Haskell, we can check everything about our types first, *throw away all that information*, and then compile something that refers only to values.  In fact, this is exactly what GHC does; since we can never check types at run-time in Haskell, GHC erases all the types at compile-time without changing the program's run-time behavior.  This is why `unsafeCoerce` is easy to implement (operationally) and completely unsafe: at run-time, it's a no-op, but it lies to the type system.  Consequently, something like `toType` is completely impossible to implement in the Haskell type system.

In fact, as you noticed, you can't even write down the desired type and use `unsafeCoerce`.  For some problems, you can get away with this; we can write down the type for the function, but only implement it with by cheating.  That's exactly how `fromDynamic` works.  But as we saw above, there's not even a good type to give to this problem from within Haskell.  The imaginary `toType` function allows you to give the program a type, but you can't even write down `toType`'s type!

### What now?

So, you can't do this.  What *should* you do?  My guess is that your overall architecture isn't ideal for Haskell, although I haven't seen it; `Typeable` and `Dynamic` don't actually show up that much in Haskell programs.  (Perhaps you're "speaking Haskell with a Python accent", as they say.)  If you only have a finite set of data types to deal with, you might be able to bundle things into a plain old algebraic data type instead:

```
data MyType = MTInt Int | MTBool Bool | MTString String
```

Then you can write `isMTInt`, and just use `filter isMTInt`, or `filter (isSameMTAs randomMT)`.

Although I don't know what it is, there's probably a way you *could* `unsafeCoerce` your way through this problem.  But frankly, that's not a good idea unless you really, really, really, really, really, *really* know what you're doing.  And even then, it's probably not.  If you need `unsafeCoerce`, you'll know, it won't just be a convenience thing.

I really agree with [Daniel Wagner's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273982/programmatic-type-annotations-in-haskell#comment16462140_12273982): you're probably going to want to rethink your approach from scratch.  Again, though, since I haven't seen your architecture, I can't say what that will mean.  Maybe there's another Stack Overflow question in there, if you can distill out a concrete difficulty.

---

<sup>1</sup> That looks like the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data TypeableList = forall a. Typeable a => TypeableList [a]
randList :: [Dynamic] -> IO TypeableList
```

However, since none of this code compiles anyway, I think writing it out with `exists` is clearer.

<sup>2</sup> Technically, there are some other functions which look relevant, such as [`toDyn :: Typeable a => a -> Dynamic`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Dynamic.html#v:toDyn) and [`fromDyn :: Typeable a => Dynamic -> a -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Dynamic.html#v:fromDyn).  However, `Dynamic` is more or less an existential wrapper around `Typeable`s, relying on `typeOf` and `TypeRep`s to know when to `unsafeCoerce` (GHC uses some implementation-specific types and `unsafeCoerce`, but you could do it this way, with the *possible* exception of `dynApply`/`dynApp`), so `toDyn` doesn't do anything new.  And `fromDyn` doesn't really expect its argument of type `a`; it's just a wrapper around `cast`.  These functions, and the other similar ones, don't provide any extra power that isn't available with just `typeOf` and `cast`.  (For instance, going *back* to a `Dynamic` isn't very useful for your problem!)

<sup>3</sup> To see the error in action, you can try to compile the following complete Haskell program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
import Data.Dynamic
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Maybe

randItem :: [a] -> IO a
randItem = return . head -- Good enough for a short and non-compiling example

dynListToList :: Typeable a => [Dynamic] -> [a]
dynListToList = mapMaybe fromDynamic

data TypeableList = forall a. Typeable a => TypeableList [a]

randList :: [Dynamic] -> IO TypeableList
randList dl = do
  tr <- randItem $ map dynTypeRep dl
  return . TypeableList $ dynListToList dl -- Error!  Ambiguous type variable.
```

Sure enough, if you try to compile this, you get the error:

```
SO12273982.hs:17:27:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
      (Typeable a0) arising from a use of `dynListToList'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `dynListToList dl'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: return . TypeableList $ dynListToList dl
    In the expression:
      do { tr <- randItem $ map dynTypeRep dl;
           return . TypeableList $ dynListToList dl }
```

But as is the entire point of the question, you *can't* "add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)", because you don't know what type you want.

<sup>4</sup> Mostly.  GHC 7.4 has support for lifting types to kinds and for kind polymorphism; see [section 7.8, "Kind polymorphism and promotion", in the GHC 7.4 user manual](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4-latest/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism-and-promotion.html).  This doesn't make Haskell dependently typed—something like `TypeRep -> *` example is still out<sup>5</sup>—but you will be able to write `Vec` by using very expressive types that *look* like values.

<sup>5</sup> Technically, you could now write down something which *looks* like it has the desired type: `type family ToType :: TypeRep -> *`.  However, this takes a *type* of the promoted *kind* `TypeRep`, and not a *value* of the *type* `TypeRep`; and besides, you still wouldn't be able to implement it.  (At least I don't think so, and I can't see how you would—but I am not an expert in this.)  But at this point, we're pretty far afield.

Comment: By `randList :: [Dynamic] -> [Typeable]` you probably mean `randList :: [Dynamic] -> [TypeRep]`, but even that is a little disingenuous since `typeOf` isn't the only thing you can do on `Typeable` values, you can also `cast` them. Additionally, where you have `randList :: [Dynamic] -> (exists (tr :: TypeRep). Typeable (toType tr) => IO [toType tr])` you probably actually want the typerep in the result as well, no? Otherwise you are just saying "the result is of a representable type", not "the result is of a representable type and this is what it is"

Comment: Ben: 1. Yes, I do mean `[TypeRep]`, thanks.  I'll fix that, just as soon as… 2. I figure out how to address your excellent point about `cast`.  (Stupid `unsafeCoerce` making my arguments invalid :-))  3. I thought about having `exists … (tr, IO [toType tr])`, but I was imagining `exists` as being a dependent sum, which could then be pattern-matched on to extract the information.  Haskell can't do that for existential types because of parametricity, but we've clearly already left parametricity well behind here :-)  If it's clearer, though, I can change it; that's probably a good idea.

Comment: I won't claim authority on the latter point - if you're confident you know what you're doing then you can leave it as it is :)

Comment: @BenMillwood: Fixed, fixed, and fixed.  (With some clarification/typo-fixing happening simultaneously.)  Thanks for catching those errors in my answer.  (Including the existential pair with `tr`; clarity is more important than potentially being technically correct, and I'm not claiming great authority in dependent types anyway!)

Answer (score 13):

What you're observing is that the type `TypeRep` doesn't actually carry any type-level information along with it; only term-level information. This is a shame, but we can do better when we know all the type constructors we care about. For example, suppose we only care about `Int`s, lists, and function types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeOperators #-}

import Control.Monad

data a :=: b where Refl :: a :=: a
data Dynamic where Dynamic :: TypeRep a -> a -> Dynamic
data TypeRep a where
    Int   :: TypeRep Int
    List  :: TypeRep a -> TypeRep [a]
    Arrow :: TypeRep a -> TypeRep b -> TypeRep (a -> b)

class Typeable a where typeOf :: TypeRep a
instance Typeable Int where typeOf = Int
instance Typeable a => Typeable [a] where typeOf = List typeOf
instance (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Typeable (a -> b) where
    typeOf = Arrow typeOf typeOf

congArrow :: from :=: from' -> to :=: to' -> (from -> to) :=: (from' -> to')
congArrow Refl Refl = Refl

congList :: a :=: b -> [a] :=: [b]
congList Refl = Refl

eq :: TypeRep a -> TypeRep b -> Maybe (a :=: b)
eq Int Int = Just Refl
eq (Arrow from to) (Arrow from' to') = liftM2 congArrow (eq from from') (eq to to')
eq (List t) (List t') = liftM congList (eq t t')
eq _ _ = Nothing

eqTypeable :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Maybe (a :=: b)
eqTypeable = eq typeOf typeOf

toDynamic :: Typeable a => a -> Dynamic
toDynamic a = Dynamic typeOf a

-- look ma, no unsafeCoerce!
fromDynamic_ :: TypeRep a -> Dynamic -> Maybe a
fromDynamic_ rep (Dynamic rep' a) = case eq rep rep' of
    Just Refl -> Just a
    Nothing   -> Nothing

fromDynamic :: Typeable a => Dynamic -> Maybe a
fromDynamic = fromDynamic_ typeOf
```

All of the above is pretty standard. For more on the design strategy, you'll want to read about GADTs and singleton types. Now, the function you want to write follows; the type is going to look a bit daft, but bear with me.

```
-- extract only the elements of the list whose type match the head
firstOnly :: [Dynamic] -> Dynamic
firstOnly [] = Dynamic (List Int) []
firstOnly (Dynamic rep v:xs) = Dynamic (List rep) (v:go xs) where
    go [] = []
    go (Dynamic rep' v:xs) = case eq rep rep' of
        Just Refl -> v : go xs
        Nothing   ->     go xs
```

Here we've picked a random element (I rolled a die, and it came up 1) and extracted only the elements that have a matching type from the list of dynamic values. Now, we *could* have done the same thing with regular boring old `Dynamic` from the standard libraries; however, what we *couldn't* have done is used the `TypeRep` in a meaningful way. I now demonstrate that we can do so: we'll pattern match on the `TypeRep`, and then use the enclosed value at the specific type the `TypeRep` tells us it is.

```
use :: Dynamic -> [Int]
use (Dynamic (List (Arrow Int Int)) fs) = zipWith ($) fs [1..]
use (Dynamic (List Int) vs) = vs
use (Dynamic Int v) = [v]
use (Dynamic (Arrow (List Int) (List (List Int))) f) = concat (f [0..5])
use _ = []
```

Note that on the right-hand sides of these equations, we are using the wrapped value *at different, concrete types*; the pattern match on the `TypeRep` is actually introducing type-level information.

Comment: This is a really excellent solution to your problem, by an excellent computer scientist, so +1, but... Don't do this! Do you _really_ need to mix up those heterogenous types? Could you _really_ not cope with using an abstract data type for a few types you want to put together in a list? Wouldn't that be more elegant? If not, couldn't you make those types instances of some typeclass and then you don't need to dig the type out again in your heterogenous list? Static typing is your friend. Static typing takes away a world of pain. Only give up on static typing if you have to.

Comment: @AndrewC FWIW I wholeheartedly agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

You want a function that chooses a different type of values to return based on runtime data. Okay, great. But the whole *purpose* of a type is to tell you what operations can be performed on a value. When you don't know what type will be returned from a function, what do you *do* with the values it returns? What operations can you perform on them? There are two options:

- You want to read the type, and perform some behaviour based on which type it is. In this case you can only cater for a finite list of types known in advance, essentially by testing "is it this type? then we do this operation...". This is easily possible in the current `Dynamic` framework: just return the `Dynamic` objects, using `dynTypeRep` to filter them, and leave the application of `fromDynamic` to whoever wants to consume your result. Moreover, it could well be possible without `Dynamic`, if you don't mind setting the finite list of types in your producer code, rather than your consumer code: just use an ADT with a constructor for each type, `data Thing = Thing1 Int | Thing2 String | Thing3 (Thing,Thing)`. This latter option is by far the best if it is possible.
- You want to perform some operation that works across a family of types, potentially some of which you don't know about yet, e.g. by using type class operations. This is trickier, and it's tricky conceptually too, because your program is not allowed to change *behaviour* based on whether or not some type class instance exists – it's an important property of the type class system that the introduction of a new instance can either make a program type check or stop it from type checking, but it can't change the behaviour of a program. Hence you can't throw an error if your input list contains inappropriate types, so I'm really not sure that there's anything you can do that doesn't essentially involve falling back to the first solution at some point.